# Detect change of radio/checkbox

Tags: jquery, checkbox, radio-button

I'm rewriting a plugin of mine and I want to try to take care of an issue we had in the past.

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mattio2187/HruGP/)

When you check the checkbox by clicking on it, the change event is triggered. It's being logged in the console.

However, if you use the button to the left of it, 'change' is not triggered.

With the plugin, I want to be able to detect this change if the user is checking the checkbox or radio button dynamically with code they already have.

Any thoughts?

HTML:

```
<input type="button" name="check" value="Checkbox" />
<input type="checkbox" name="newsletter" value="true" />​
```

jQuery:

```
$(function() {

    // This toggle checks and unckecks the box
    $('input:button').toggle(function() {
        $('input:checkbox').prop("checked", true);
    }, function() {
        $('input:checkbox').prop("checked", false);
    });


    // Detects change of checkbox           
    $('input:checkbox').on("change", function() {
        console.log('checked!');
    });

});​
```

Answer (score 1):

Easiest fix is to fire the change event manually:

```
$('input:checkbox').prop("checked", true).change();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HruGP/1/

**Edit:** You can also simplify your button code instead of using `toggle`, just use a `click` and assign the `checked` property to the opposite of its current value:

```
$('input:button').on('click',function() {
    var $checkbox = $('input:checkbox');
    $checkbox.prop('checked', !$checkbox.is(':checked')).change();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HruGP/3/

Answer (score 0):

You could just fire the click event on the checkbox, instead of changing the property manually:

```
$('input:checkbox').click();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input:button').click(function(){
    $('input:checkbox').trigger("change");
});
```

this allows the "change" event to be triggered when you click on the button

Answer (score 0):

Yep trigger the check box, I'd do it this way (replacing the first part of the code in your fiddle):

```
// This toggle checks and unckecks the box
$('input:button').on('click', function(event){
    $('input:checkbox').trigger('click');             
});
```

Assuming of course that your goal is to basically make the button the way in which you check or uncheck the box.